# Proving the Partial Fraction Decomposition of the Hyperbolic Cotangent Function by using Poisson Summation

Tags: solution-verification, hyperbolic-functions, poisson-summation-formula

While skimming through the wonderful post *What are some examples of colorful language in serious mathematics papers?* on MathOverflow [an example given by Ben Green](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22349) made me curious. He referred to the  Poisson Summation Formula, which I heard from for the first time. According to [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonSumFormula.html) the Poisson Summation Formula is given by

> $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x+n)~=~\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i kx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{-2\pi ikx'}\mathrm dx'\tag1$$

Denote the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ by $\hat f(\xi)$. Evaluating at $x=0$ reduces $(1)$ to the more common formulation, as it is also stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Forms_of_the_equation)

> $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)~=~\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(k)\tag2$$

Anyway, within the Wikipedia entry there is an [*Example* section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Examples). One of the examples is the partial fraction decomposition of the hyperbolic cotagent function. To be precise it is given that

> > $f(x)=e^{-ax}$ for $0\leq x$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ to get $\coth(x)=\frac1x+2x\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z^+}\frac1{x^2+\pi^2n^2}$, the partial fraction decomposition of $\coth(x)$

As far as I can tell the here used function $f(x)$ is wrong. I think it should be a bilateral exponential which vanishs for $\pm\infty$ but has an actual value for $x<0$. In other words I would say that the function $f(x)$ should be defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-ax}&,x\ge 0\\e^{ax}&,x<0\end{cases}$$

Here $a$ denotes a positive real constant. Clearly $f(x)$ is an even function from which it follows directly that $f(x)=f(-x)$. Utlizing this definition we can explicitly write the LHS of $(2)$ as

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\hat f(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$

Now note that $f(n)=e^{-an}$ for all $n\ge1$. Thus, we obtain that

$$f(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-an}=1+\frac{2e^{-a}}{1-e^{-a}}=\frac{e^a+1}{e^a-1}=\coth\left(\frac a2\right)$$

The Fourier Transform $\hat f(\xi)$ of $f(x)$ can be computed by splitting the region of integration and recombining the results afterwards. Overall this sums up to

$$\hat f(\xi)=\frac1{a+2\pi i\xi}+\frac1{a-2\pi i\xi}=\frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2\xi^2}$$

Again $\hat f(\xi)$ is clearly even from which we can conclude that $\hat f(\xi)=\hat f(-\xi)$ and therefore the RHS of $(2)$ becomes

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(k)=\hat f(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hat f(k)$$

Finally we obtain

$$\hat f(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hat f(k)=\frac2a f(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2k^2}=\frac2a+2\left(\frac a2\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\left(\frac a2\right)^2+\pi^2k^2}$$

Utilizing the whole equation $(2)$ again and by chosing $a=2a$ we obtain the desired forumla.

> $$\therefore~\coth(a)~=~\frac1a+2a\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{a^2+\pi^2k^2}\tag2$$

However, I claim that the function Wikipedia gives *does not* produce the here proved formula $(3)$. According to my own calculation the RHS indeed equals the partial fraction decomposition of the hyperbolic cotangent function whereas the LHS is missing a factor $2$ infront of the infinite sum from where it is not deducable that the LHS is in fact the hyperbolic cotagent.

> Two questions, closely related: First of all is the identity denoted as $(3)$ derivable from the applying Poisson Summation on the function given on Wikipedia? Is my own solution one the on hand correct but perhaps to complicated since my choice of $f(x)$ for $x<0$ might be redundant if the function given by Wikipedia is sufficient for this purpose? I appreciate every suggestion of either improving my own proof or explaining me what I am missing about the function stated on Wikipedia.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \not \in 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$ $$G(x) = e^{-ax} 1_{x \in [0,1]}, \qquad g(x) = \sum_n G(x+n)$$ piecewise $C^1$ and $1$-periodic.

Then $$\hat{g}(k) = \int_0^1 g(x)e^{-2i \pi kx}dx = \frac{1-e^{-a}}{a+2i \pi k}$$ And by the Fourier series theorem for piecewise $C^1$ periodic functions $$\frac{1+e^{-a}}{2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{G(x)+G(-x)}{2}  = \lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K \hat{g}(k) = (1-e^{-a}) \lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K \frac{1}{a+2i \pi k}$$